# Memory game error with keeping matched pairs face up. what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am programming a MEMORY MATCH GAME. Click a card, it will turn face up. Click a second card, and it will also turn face up. If the two cards match, they will disappear. If not match, they will remain face down.

My program: If you click first card, it turn will face up,no problem. But if you click the second card, it doesn't turn face up.

```
public void onMouseClicked(TileUIController eventController, TileUIController matchedController, MouseEvent event, GameUI gameUI) {
    if (displayCard1 == null || displayCard2 == null) {//只翻起一张牌，或未翻起牌

        if (displayCard1 == null) {//未翻起牌 there is no card has been clicked
            displayCard1 = eventController;
        } else {//翻起了一张牌//there is already one card has been clicked
            if (displayCard1.equals(eventController)) {//是同一张牌被点击，不做任何处理if is the same card to be clicked
                return;
            }
            displayCard2 = eventController;
        }
        hitSound.play();
        faceUp(eventController);//make card to be face up

    }


    //两张牌都被翻起if there are already tow cards,check if they match
    if (displayCard1 != null && displayCard2 != null) {
        boolean isMatch = isMatch(displayCard1, displayCard2, event);
        if(isMatch){
           disappearTwoCards(displayCard1,displayCard2);
        }else{
           faceDownTwoCards(displayCard1,displayCard2);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
private void faceUp(TileUIController controller) {

    controller.getImageView().setImage(new Image("upImage"));

}
private void faceDown(TileUIController controller) {
    //将image设置为cardback，感觉像翻过去了
    controller.getImageView().setImage(new Image("backImage"));

}
```

why only the first card will face up?the second card won't face up.

（My English is too bad,sorry and thank you guys!）

Comment: I guess when the two cards are not same, i.e. isMatch is false, then it actually facing up but immediately facing down because isMatch=false on second click.

Comment: but if I add 'Thread.sleep(1000)' after face up,before fece down,it also won't face up.

Comment: Thread.sleep will delay the current thread which is JavaFX main ui thread, so you will not able to observe the gui change (facing up) in that period.

Comment: Thank you very much!!!   Really helpful! I tried Timer,the tow cards turned face up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the 2nd card is clicked, it gets facing up but facing down immediately afterwards because isMatch=false, so that you cannot observe the facing up in between.

There should be some delay for animation between facing up and down. Using Thread.sleep is not an option, since it will delay the current thread which is JavaFX main ui thread, so you will not able to observe the gui change (facing up) in that period.